# Syntax error in Try & Catch

Tags: java, syntax, try-catch, token

I am having issues completing a Try and Catch. I keep getting a syntax error asking for "(" "{" ";" tokens where they are not needed at. Searched all over the for answer and I have yet to come to a conclusion as to why I keep getting this error. Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Browser extends Application{

final Button Back = new Button("<-");
final Button Forward = new Button ("->");
final Button Home = new Button("Home");
final Button Reload = new Button("r");
final MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
final TextField txt = new TextField();

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    VBox hBox = new VBox();
    WebView wv = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = wv.getEngine();
    WebHistory wh = engine.getHistory();
    engine.load("https://www.google.com");

    txt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        try{
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                engine.load(txt.getText());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            showError("Unable to load site");
        }
    });
    hBox.getChildren().setAll(txt, wv);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 800, 600);
    stage.setTitle("Anthony Gayflor-CS260 OOP");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

private void showError(String errorMessage){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, errorMessage, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

when I compile it, the error I get is

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

at Browser.start(Browser.java:33)
```

Comment: You can't wrap a method in a try-catch block.

Comment: Have try-catch inside> public void handle(ActionEvent event)

Comment: I suppose you're right haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Jens' answer, you can use lambda in Java 8, because `EventHandler` is a functional interface. Then your code will look like:

```
txt.setOnAction(event -> {
    try {
        engine.load(txt.getText());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        showError("Unable to load site");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try-catch` block must be inside of the method:

```
 public void handle(ActionEvent event){
    try{
            engine.load(txt.getText());
    }catch(Exception e){
           showError("Unable to load site");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to define a method in a try / catch clause !!!

Put the try / catch clause into a method.